# How to understand tee command?

Tags: bash

My directory has four files:

```
1 2 3 4
```

then I run command

```
ls | tee >(ls) | more
```

it will print

```
1
3
2
4
1
2
3
4
```

but when I run

```
ls | tee>(echo hello) | more
```

there are just

```
hello
```

Why? In the first command,the first ls 's result will be directed to more and the second ls 's result will also be directed to more.
But In the second command, why ls's result didn't be directed to more?

By the way , what is > mean?

Answer (score 7):

Normally `>` is the operator used to redirect standard out to a file. Here, it's using a feature of Bash known as [*process substitution*](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html), which allows you to substitute a process's standard input or output for an expected output file or input file (respectively).

### tee

Usually, `tee` will write its standard input to the filename you tell it, as well as its standard output.  It effectively puts a "T" in the data pipeline.

```
foo | tee foo.out | bar
```

Results in:

```
foo --> tee --> bar
         |
         V
      foo.out
```

### Process substitution

Process substitution is a feature of Bash that causes the shell to open a named pipe to your process being substituted for a file, and pass that named pipe in place of the filename.  Example:

```
diff <(echo hello) <(echo goodbye)
```

Results in

```
echo hello > /dev/fd/63 &
echo hello > /dev/fd/62 &
diff /dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/62
```

### Combining tee and process substitution

```
ls | tee >(ls) | more
```

Doesn't matter because `ls` doesn't even look at its standard input. So you have:

```
ls < /dev/fd/63 &       # which never gets read

ls --> tee --> more
        |
        V
    /dev/fd/63
```

So first you see the `ls` in parenthesis output the listing of your directory (it never reads the stdin you give it). Then you see `more` print the output from the first `ls`. The output of `tee` is lost, because you sent it to the other `ls`. The result? The output of `ls` *twice*.

Comment: Didn't you want to explain the missing space in `tee>(echo hello)`, which means that the second example never manages to run `tee` (and, presumably,, `more` has hijacked the terminal and hidden the error message, or OP just ignored the error all by themselves)? Anyway, +1:: great ascii art.

Comment: @rici Ah, I missed that. I'm exhausted of this question however. I think your comment does it justice though.

Comment: the ls in parenthesis  is just like a file, then why a file's content will be directed to stdout?

Answer (score 0):

if i have directory 1,2,3,4

Then the command

ls | tee

it shows

1

2

3

4

tee command is used for showing standard outputs.

then  run

ls| tee< file2.txt

the above command redirecting output to  file2.txt

open the file fil2.txt

vim file2.txt

u will see following output

1

2

3

4

file2.txt

Comment: ls |tee< file2.txt? I can't see what you see.